# how to publish scalajs plugin for sbt 1.0 in local

Tags: scala.js

https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/DEVELOPING.md#publish-locally

Tried So far :

```
> ^^ 1.0.2
> ;ir/publishLocal;tools/publishLocal;jsEnvs/publishLocal;jsEnvsTestKit/publishLocal;nodeJSEnv/publishLocal;testAdapter/publishLocal;sbtPlugin/publishLocal
```

Error :

`[error] (sbtPlugin/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-native#sbt-crossproject;0.2.1: not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do `++2.12.3` first:

```
> ++2.12.3
> ^^1.0.2
> ;ir/publishLocal;...
```